# Can I create a pthread inside a pthread, which is already created by the main?

Tags: c++, sockets, posix

Will I run into an error if I create a pthread_create inside a pthread, which is created by the main function. If, I can then what all things I should take care of???

Important....:I am doing a socket programming, where I have opened 5 threads each on separate ports which are listening on ports, when ever I receive a message, I want to create a thread which takes the message and writes into a file using pwrite. So, I have a few questions, please can you help me???

If not then what is another solution of creating a thread inside a thread..??

Or will it give me a segmentation fault???

or will I run into some race conditions....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pthread_create` creates a new thread.  Independently of where it is
called.  And creating a new thread for a connection when listening on a
port is pretty much standard procedure.

Comment: But, my question is I have taken the data from recv thread and the sent it as an arguement to the thread created after recv.... Now as there are 5 threads simultaneously listening, will it not create a race condition in the received packets.....

Comment: @Invictus Regardless of where you create the threads, you have to follow the usual rules for thread safety.  A lot depends on how you are "listening" using `accept`, each returned `int` is a separate socket, which can be passed to the child thread without problems.  If you're handling a UDP connection, and listening using `recvfrom`, you should allocate a new buffer for each call, and pass the received buffer to the child thread, which can free it when it is through.  In both cases, each thread should be listening to a different socket (port).